# Postman Authorization API-Key

Tags: api, authentication, get, postman

I am trying to use the Privacy API but the Authorization Header is confusing me a lot. I am not sure how to format the header no matter what method I use for calling the request.
Below is the exact format they asked me to use but now I'm not getting any response. If anyone knows how to authorize Privacy's request calls it would help me so much, thank you in advance! [Privacy API](https://developer.privacy.com/docs#authentication)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If picture describe what you try to do, remove two dots after Autorization in Key input
Key: Autorization (without two dots on the end)
value: api-key xxxxx